# Practicality of comparing a list representation of a dates or comparing datetime objects

Tags: python, json, datetime

The following JSON item was generated in the following ways:

- DateTime was used to parse and collect the date
- attributes were extracted and added to a list; `[<year>, <month>, <day>]`
- and the json output format was as follows

```
"English HW 2": {
        "major": false,
        "due date": [
            2021,
            1,
            11
        ]
    }
```

I am making a sorting program that will weigh assignments by their urgency, I need to first take the due dates into account. My real query comes in when I want to compare and group dates. It's pretty simple to do but I wanted to make sure that I was doing this efficiently and without too much redundancy.

The crux of my "problem" is that I have dates stored in a list `[<year>, <month>, <day>]` which I can directly compare to each other without having to convert to DateTime and then compare. Should I just avoid DateTime entirely for this, it's only being used to hold the data, and it would be much more direct to just feed inputs to a date "array".

What's the best practice here? Which is faster?

Comment: I've had good results with strings in `YYYY-MM-DD` format to represent dates in json.

Comment: so you're saying i should stick with using datetime and parse those on retrevial?

Comment: If you only care that a date is before, after, or equal to another date, then you can use direct string comparison with `YYYY-MM-DD` formats and not worry about datetime at all.  But if your needs are more complex, i.e. you need to know _how many days_ apart two dates are, then you will need to parse that string into a datetime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in performance - why not benchmark it. Here's a basic script to do just that. TLDR: the list comparison is fastest, with strings second and datetime third, a distant third if you include the time taken to initialise the datetime objects.

However, these are all so fast that unless you are planning to roll this out on an industrial scale it is negligible. I'd say best practice is just to do whatever results in the most easily readable and maintainable code for your current need. You can refactor later if you need datetimes.

```
from time import perf_counter
import datetime

t = perf_counter()

date_as_list_1 = [2020, 10, 2]
date_as_list_2 = [2020, 10, 3]



tic = perf_counter()
date_as_list_1>date_as_list_2
toc = perf_counter()

print(f'Compare lists: {(toc-tic) * 1000}ms')

tic = perf_counter()
date_as_dt_1 = datetime.datetime(*date_as_list_1)
date_as_dt_2 = datetime.datetime(*date_as_list_2)
toc = perf_counter()

print(f'Convert to datetimes: {(toc-tic) * 1000}ms')

tic = perf_counter()
date_as_dt_1>date_as_dt_2
toc = perf_counter()

print(f'Compare datetimes: {(toc-tic) * 1000}ms')

tic = perf_counter()
'2020-10-2'>'2020-10-3'
toc = perf_counter()

print(f'Compare strings: {(toc-tic) * 1000}ms')
```

---

```
Compare lists: 0.0007760000000009426ms
Convert to datetimes: 0.004738000000004128ms
Compare datetimes: 0.0041620000000019974ms
Compare strings: 0.0014299999999967117ms
```